# Is there a way to override the app.config settings in a class (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

I'm guessing the answer to this is probably no but it'd save me a bunch of re-work so it's better to ask right?

It looks like some time ago one of our dev's ran into this same issue [Microsoft.Threading.Tasks referencing an incorrect System.Threading.Tasks.dll version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35431993/microsoft-threading-tasks-referencing-an-incorrect-system-threading-tasks-dll-ve) and used the same solution in one of the shared projects(we're using C# and .Net 4.6). The problem is that this appears to have broken one of the other legacy systems in that project, something that only get run annually so no one knew there was an issue until now (unit tests all passed).

I can't remove the binding re-direct which leaves me with two options
A) Figure out if a class can override the settings in the app config to use a different version of System.Threading.Tasks
OR
B) Re-architect the legacy system and solve the issue that way.

So i'm just checking if it is possible to specify a specific version of System.Threading.Tasks in a class in such a way that it won't be overwritten by the projects app.config ?

Comment: Do you mean to allow one class to use one version of `System.Threading.Tasks` and another class to use a different version? Within the same process and app domain? Don't think that is possible.

Comment: Pretty much. I don't think it is but i thought it best to check